# g++-4.1 ambiguous class template instantiation workaround?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

This code, which is accepted by other compilers, fails with `g++-4.1`:

```
template<typename T> struct foo;

template<template<typename> class ClassTemplate, typename Arg>
  struct foo<ClassTemplate<Arg> >
{
  typedef Arg type;
};

template<template<typename, typename> class ClassTemplate, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
  struct foo<ClassTemplate<Arg1,Arg2> >
{
  typedef Arg1 type;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2 = int> class bar {};

int main()
{
  typedef bar<int> test_me;
  typedef foo<test_me>::type type;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler output:

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for ‘struct foo<bar<int, int> >’
test.cpp:5: error: candidates are: struct foo<ClassTemplate<Arg> >
test.cpp:11: error:                 struct foo<ClassTemplate<Arg1, Arg2> >
test.cpp:20: error: ‘type’ in class ‘foo<bar<int, int> >’ does not name a type
```

The existence of `bar`'s default template parameter seems to be the culprit.

Is there any other way I could implement `foo` for this compiler?

Comment: Should not there be a `typename` in `typedef foo<test_me>::type type;`? Like `typedef typename foo<test_me>::type type;`.

Comment: No, `typename` is not to be used outside of templates, and `main` is not a template.

Comment: ___Inside a template definition, typename can be used to declare that a dependent name is a type.___ See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename).

Comment: Or better yet, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx).